# HeaderedContentControl header template not being used

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm fairly new to WPF and am working with some legacy code, not sure how to use the HeaderedContentControl Header. I'd like to put in a StackPanel and customize the look of a header, just not sure how to do that.

Could someone give me some guidance on what to do next?

I have this xaml and the HeaderTemplate is never used.

```
<UserControl x:Class="PEC.Admin.WindowsControls.Program.Views.ProgramProductEnrichmentColorsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:commonControls="clr-namespace:ManagerConsole.Common.Controls;assembly=ManagerConsole.Common.Controls"
         xmlns:program="clr-namespace:PEC.Admin.ViewModel.Program;assembly=PEC.Admin.ViewModel.Program"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignWidth="300" 
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance program:ProgramProductEnrichmentColorsViewModel}">
    <commonControls:ExpanderPanel IsExpanded="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate> <!-- this never gets used... -->
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Header}"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Width="Auto"
                    Margin="3"
                    Background="White">
            <TextBlock Text="Source Type:"
                       Margin="0,5,0,0" />
            <TextBox IsReadOnly="True"
                     IsTabStop="False"
                     Background="LightGray"
                     BorderThickness="0"
                     Text="{Binding Path=SourceTypeName, Mode=OneTime}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </commonControls:ExpanderPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HeaderTemplate *is* applied. To verify it - set a background to the Label in HeaderTemplate.

HeaderTemplate doesn't display anything though, because binding is incorrect. Template is applied to the data set in `Header` property, which currently has `null` value.

So change code as in the example below (I tried with Expander, hopefully it will work for custom commonControls:ExpanderPanel):

```
<Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          Header="{Binding ComplexObject}">
  <HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Background="Green" Content="{Binding PropertyOfTheObject}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate>
</Expander>
```

Header is a dependency property and can be set via Binding. Header becomes a source for bindings in a HeaderTemplate. Or it can be some constant (`Header="Click to expand"`), resource (`Header="{StaticResource ExpandTitle}"`) or complex content, e.g.:

```
<Expander.Header>
   <TextBlock Text="Click to expand"/>
</Expander.Header>
```

Comment: thanks for that...My only problem is that I'm trying to bind to more than just a string. `Header` is actually a type with two properties, both of which are strings. How can I bind the header, which is a complex object to the template. Thanks